# In Cocoa, do you have to do anything special to make sure you copy resource forks when copying files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file-io

I had assume I could just do this, but I don't have a way to check that resource forks went along for the ride.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fm copyPath:absSourcePath toPath:absDestinationPath handler:err];
```

edit: I need to copy in a 10.4-6 compatible manner. (Yes, really 10.4.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, everything gets copied, including file permissions, subdirectories, symbolic links, you name it.  The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) recommends using `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` in 10.5 and later, so you might want to work that in if possible.  It's not available on 10.4, so you'll have to use `copyPath:toPath:handler:` there.

I guess I should note, it may depend on the destination filesystem;  I don't know what would happen if it didn't support resource forks.  I guess it would use [Apple Double](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20578)?

Answer (score 4):

NSFileManager copies the resource fork. You don't have to do anything.

Yesterday I posted a comparison I have made of different properties that are copied/lost when copying files. I test NSFileManager as well and it does a better job than most other tools when copying files.

[image: Comparison of tools and preservation of meta data]

[see it in full size](http://www.flickr.com/photos/12739382@N04/4056132709/sizes/o/)

The reason it's red for NSFileManager in the "50" column, is that NSFileManager doesn't detect hardlinked files. So instead of making hardlinks it creates the same file multiple times, will data fork + resource fork. So resource fork works.

My code is inspired by [backup bouncer](http://www.n8gray.org/code/backup-bouncer/)

Comment: +1 for great comparison table! -1 for 10.5 while 10.4 was explicitely asked for.

Comment: thanks. I haven't yet run any tests on 10.4 nor 10.6. A big comparison across different OS versions would indeed be nice. I will have to rethink some things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this still works, but I haven't seen a file with a resource fork in some time, so I can't say for certain.

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2002022409532098